# RealityKit – How to edit or add a Lighting?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to add lighting in my RealityKit AR Scene. And I can't find the Lighting option in Reality Composer. If there's a way to add `Directional Light` or edit it then please tell me. I've tried Apple Documentation but can't understand how to add them.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your image in stackoverflow rather than using an external service. If your image gets removed, the question will not make sense for future people having a similar issue.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try

Comment: It won't allow me to add image.

Comment: since I don't have enough points. It says 10 points to add image in post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment you can't do it in Reality Composer, you need to use a RealityKit. So, you need to create a custom class that inherits from `Entity` class and conforms to `HasPointLight` protocol. Run this code in macOS project to find out how a PointLight setup works:

```
import AppKit
import RealityKit

class Lighting: Entity, HasPointLight {
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        
        self.light = PointLightComponent(color: .red,
                                     intensity: 100000,
                             attenuationRadius: 20)
    }
}

class GameViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        
        arView.environment.background = .color(.black)
        
        let pointLight = Lighting().light
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        
        boxAnchor.components.set(pointLight)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        boxAnchor.steelBox!.scale = [9,9,9]
        boxAnchor.steelBox!.position.z = -0.5
    }
}
```

[image]

> The same way you can add a Directional Light to the scene. But remember: a position of Directional Light does not important, but an orientation does! By default it's oriented to north (-Z).

```
class Lighting: Entity, HasDirectionalLight {
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        
        self.light = DirectionalLightComponent(color: .red,
                                           intensity: 100000,
                                    isRealWorldProxy: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Also can read my [STORY](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-lighting-and-shadows-66f99bcd5219) about lights on Medium.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try

Comment: Thanks man. The lighting works. But the shadows are still too dark. Actually I want the shadows to be dimmed. Is there a way for that?

Comment: Saad, please, publish another question (and give me a link here). I'll try to answer it.

Comment: I asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782819/how-can-i-reduce-the-intensity-of-the-shadows-of-these-models-in-reality-kit