# How can I reduce the opacity of the shadows in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I composed a scene in Reality Composer and added 3 objects in it. The problem is that the shadows are too intense (dark).

I tried using the Directional Light in RealityKit from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747147/realitykit-how-to-edit-or-add-a-lighting/59756368?noredirect=1#comment105708880_59756368) answer rather than a default light from Reality Composer (since you don't have an option to adjust light in it).

[image]

**Update**
I implemented the spotlight Lighting as explained by @AndyFedo in the answer. The shadow is still so dark.

[image]

Comment: That's just the matter of moving the object away from the light source or the other way around, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shadows appear darker when I use "Hide" action sequence on "Scene Start" and post a notification to call "Show" action sequence on tap gesture. 
The shadows were fixed when I scaled the Object to 0% and post Notification to call "Move,Rotate,Scale to" action sequence on tap gesture.

**Scaled Image**

[image]

**Unhide Image**

[image]

**Object Difference with hidden and scaled actions**

[image]

```
import UIKit

import RealityKit

import ARKit


class Lighting: Entity, HasDirectionalLight {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.light = DirectionalLightComponent(color: .red, intensity: 1000, isRealWorldProxy: true)
    }
}

class SpotLight: Entity, HasSpotLight {

    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.light = SpotLightComponent(color: .yellow,
                                        intensity: 50000,
                                        innerAngleInDegrees: 90,
                                        outerAngleInDegrees: 179, // greater angle – softer shadows
            attenuationRadius: 10) // can't be Zero

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    enum TapObjects {
        case None
        case HiddenChair
        case ScaledChair
    }    
    var furnitureAnchor : Furniture._Furniture!
    var tapObjects : TapObjects = .None

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        furnitureAnchor = try! Furniture.load_Furniture()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(furnitureAnchor)

        addTapGesture()

    }

    func addTapGesture() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        switch tapObjects {
        case .None:
            furnitureAnchor.notifications.unhideChair.post()
            tapObjects = .HiddenChair
        case .HiddenChair:
            furnitureAnchor.notifications.scaleChair.post()
            tapObjects = .ScaledChair
        default:
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you fo with the SpotLight and Lighting classes? You're not using them in your code

Comment: I used a different notification instead of using the lights

Answer (score 4):

> **In case you need soft and semi-transparent shadows in your scene**, use `SpotLight` lighting fixture which is available when you use a `SpotLight` class or implement `HasSpotLight` protocol. By default `SpotLight` is north-oriented. At the moment there's no `opacity` instance property for shadows in RealityKit.

`outerAngleInDegrees` instance property must be not more than **`179 degrees`**.

```
import RealityKit

class Lighting: Entity, HasSpotLight {
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        
        self.light = SpotLightComponent(color: .yellow,
                                    intensity: 50000,
                          innerAngleInDegrees: 90,
                          outerAngleInDegrees: 179,  // greater angle – softer shadows
                            attenuationRadius: 10)   // can't be Zero
    }
}
```

Then create `shadow` instance:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() { 
        arView.environment.background = .color(.black)
        
        let spotLight = Lighting().light
        let shadow = Lighting().shadow
        let boxAndCurlAnchor = try! Experience.loadBoxAndCurl()
                
        boxAndCurlAnchor.components.set(shadow!)
        boxAndCurlAnchor.components.set(spotLight)

        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAndCurlAnchor)
    }
}
```

Here's an image produced without this line: `boxAnchor.components.set(shadow!)`.

[image]

Here's an image produced with the following value `outerAngleInDegrees = 140`:

[image]

Here's an image produced with the following value `outerAngleInDegrees = 179`:

[image]

> In a room keep SpotLight fixture at a height of 2...4 meters from a model.

For bigger objects you must use higher values for `intensity` and `attenuationRadius`:

```
self.light = SpotLightComponent(color: .white,
                            intensity: 625000,
                  innerAngleInDegrees: 10,
                  outerAngleInDegrees: 120,
                    attenuationRadius: 10000)
```

[image]

Also you can read my [STORY](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-lighting-and-shadows-66f99bcd5219) about RealityKit lights on Medium.

Comment: I added this but the shadow seems not to change :(

Comment: What's a distance between model and light fixture?

Comment: I didn't change any distance for the lighting. I just added the model in my ARView. I didn't use the dark background.

Comment: What's a format of this model: `rcproject` or `usdz`?

Comment: Who did make this model, you or not?

Comment: No I didn't make this model. My artist did. Actually these models work perfect in ARScene without Reality Composer. Dunno why it's acting weird in Realty Composer.

Comment: Could you upload it on a file hosting service? I'll take a look.

Comment: I need a registration there. Could you use other hosting service (without registration)?

Comment: The shadow is not even working for the built in usdz files in Reality Composer. I found the problem. It was with the Behaviours in Reality Kit. When I hide them on session start and unhide them on tap, the shadow gets too dark. But when I scale down them on session start and scale up on tap, the shadow is perfect.