# SceneKit and ARKit – Soft shadows or blurred shadows

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have set up shadow in ARKit, But it's not satisfied results, we have required the same shade as quick view in safari. Please help me how to set up it. We have attached two images.

**Code**

```
var light = SCNLight()
var lightNode = SCNNode()
light.castsShadow = true
light.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
light.maximumShadowDistance = 20.0
light.orthographicScale = 1
light.type = .directional
light.shadowMapSize = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 2048)
light.shadowMode = .deferred
light.shadowSampleCount = 128
light.shadowRadius = 3
light.shadowBias = 32
light.zNear = 1
light.zFar = 1000
light.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.36)
lightNode.light = light2
lightNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi / 2, 0, 0)
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Provide shadow offset and increase the shadow radius. Play with these values to get the desired output.

```
light.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1) //controls spread
light.shadowOpacity = 0.5  // controls opacity
light.shadowRadius = 5.0 // controls blur level
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more blurry shadows in your scene use a greater values for `shadowRadius` instance property. `shadowRadius` specifies the sample radius used to render the receiver’s shadow.

**Default value is 3.0**.

```
var shadowRadius: CGFloat { get set }
```

...in real code it looks like this:

```
lightNode.light?.shadowRadius = 20.0
```

Apple documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlight/1523724-shadowradius):

> **`shadowRadius` is a number that specifies the amount of blurring around the edges of shadows cast by the light**. SceneKit produces soft-edged shadows by rendering the silhouettes of geometry into a 2D shadow map and then using several weighted samples from the shadow map to determine the strength of the shadow at each pixel in the rendered scene. This property controls the radius of shadow map sampling. Lower numbers result in shadows with sharply defined, pixelated edges, **higher numbers result in blurry shadows**.

Also, use a spotlight instead of directional light, `cause the first one produces nice and blurry shadows.

```
lightNode.light?.type = .spot
```

And one more tip: keep you spotlight fixture at the distance of more than 2 meters from model, and assign a value of 179 degrees to `spotOuterAngle` instance property:

```
lightNode.light?.spotOuterAngle = 179.0    /* default is 45 degrees */
```

**P.S.**

**If you wanna know how to use blurred shadows in RealityKit, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782819/how-can-i-reduce-the-opacity-of-the-shadows-in-realitykit/59786809#59786809).**